# assign events to dynamic elements

Tags: php, jquery, html

I am triying to make a grid of numbers, when the user click one field, it shows the number selected. But when i try to access the item selected cant find how to access the value of element.

```js
$(document).on('click','[id^="item"]',()=>{
    console.log($(this).prop('id'))//return undefined
    let identidad=$(this)
    console.log(identidad)//return a window element
})
```

I tried this too..

```js
$(document).ready(()=>{

 $('.item').click(()=>{
  console.log($(this).attr('data-value'))//return undefined
    console.log($(this).val())//return Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined
    console.log($(this).attr('value')//return undefined
 })

});
```

```html
    echo "
  <div id='grid'>
        <table>
            ";
            echo "<tr>";
                for ($i=1; $i <=500; $i++) { 
                echo "
                <td class='item active' id='item".$i."' value='".$i."'>".str_pad($i, 3, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT)."</td>   
                ";
                if ($i%10==0 || $i==0)  {
            echo "</tr><tr>";
            }
        }
        echo "  
    </table>        
</div>";
```

I`m starting coding so i glad any comment or suggest...

Comment: did you tried the code manually before `for` loop?? .. for me `$(this).attr('value')` should work correctly unless if you have something wrong in your code

Comment: Yes, if i bind a event $('#item1).toggleClass('active') it works fine... The thing is that i have 500 or 1000 little butoms like that...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of jQuery 3.0, .`delegate()` has been deprecated. It was superseded by the `.on()` method since jQuery 1.7, so its use was already discouraged.

```
$("table").on( ".item", "click",()=>{
        //...
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [**delegate**](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) to set event for dynamic element like this:

```
$("table").delegate( ".item", "click",()=>{
        //...
})
```

Comment: As this documents `delegate` is deprecrated http://googleweblight.com/i?u=http://api.jquery.com/delegate/&grqid=1fmPPnQV&hl=en-IN

Comment: @TusharAcharekar Thanks for comment. I used it without pay attention to `As of jQuery 3.0, .delegate() has been deprecated`. +1 for your answer for this comment.

Answer (score 0):

try to use data-value attribute instead of value also val() is used for input fields not for tables

In PHP

```
<td class='item active' id='item".$i."' data-value='".$i."'>".str_pad($i, 3, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT)."</td>
```

In JQuery

```
$('.item').click(()=>{
        console.log($(this).attr('data-value'))//this return undefined
    console.log($(this).text())//this return error toLowerCase jquery
    })
```

Comment: Good try, i like this idea but, not work... What should i try? Anything else?